# Turn off upper and lower fence plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to turn off the upper and lower fence hover information in plotly? I generally think they are ugly and not very informative. I'd like to keep the other hover information. I'd ultimately like to do this in violin plots but it might be a bit more complicated.

working example for boxplots

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

y0 = np.random.randn(50) - 1
y1 = np.random.randn(50) + 1
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y0))
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y1))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A boxplot without its whiskers is just a rectangle. But if you really wish to shave them off while keeping the hoverdata, the easiest way would be to hide them by making them the same color as the background. Unfortunately you'll need to declare the fill color because it'll default to the same color as the line.

```py
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y0,
    fillcolor='blue',
    marker_color='blue',
    line_color='white')
)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y1,
    fillcolor='red',
    marker_color='red',
    line_color='white')
)

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white')

fig.show()
```

[image: figure]

Comment: I see my question wasn't worded very well. I'd actually like to turn off the hover information for upper/lower fence.